# How can turtles move on a GIS road network based on distance?

Tags: gis, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have two types of turtles: shoppers and shops.

I want shoppers to go to the shop that is closest to them based on a real GIS road network. So, I need the shoppers to:

1. calculate the distance between them and every shop using the gis road network;
2. move to the closest shop using the gis road network and return to their starting point.
   Please help! Thanks!

Here is the link for the shapefile if it helps: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/af1a09969934851a98af90204531674f20220421103304/213277

```
 extensions [gis
      nw]
    
    globals [road-dataset]
    breed [Shoppers shopper]
    breed [shops shop]
    breed [nodes node]
    
    to setup
      ca
      create-shoppers 500
      ask shoppers [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set size 1 set color grey]
      create-shops 100
      ask shops [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set size 1 set shape "square" set color green]
      set road-dataset gis:load-dataset "/Users/amik89/Documents/Roads.shp"
      gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of road-dataset))
      gis:import-wms-drawing "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?" "EPSG:4326" "OSM-WMS" 1
foreach gis:feature-list-of road-dataset[
i ->
  foreach gis:vertex-lists-of i[
  j ->
  let first-node-point nobody
  let previous-node-point nobody
    foreach j [
    k ->
    let location gis:location-of k
    if not empty? location [
    ifelse any? nodes with [xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 location]
    []
    [
    create-nodes 1[
    set xcor item 0 location
    set ycor item 1 location
    set size 0.23
    set shape "circle"
    set color 23
    set hidden? true
    ]
  ]
;to create links
  let node-here (nodes with [xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 location])
  ifelse previous-node-point = nobody
  [set first-node-point node-here]
  [let who-node 0
   let who-prev 0
   ask node-here
   [create-street-with previous-node-point
   set who-node who]
   ask previous-node-point[
   set who-prev who
   ]
 ]
  set previous-node-point one-of node-here
 ]]]]
     reset-ticks
    end
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ? What cannot you achieve, what did you try to do ?

Comment: In the line above, I can’t make the turtles calculate the distance and move using the road network.